# Problem about linear combinations of real numbers over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have the following problem that might be silly but I am not able to find a solution.

> Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be real numbers such that $a_1,\dots,a_n,\pi$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$. Let $b_1,\dots,b_n$ be real numbers such that $b_i\notin\pi\Bbb Q$ for any $i=1,\dots,n$. I am wondering if there is $h\in\Bbb Z$ such that $ha_1+b_1,\dots,ha_n+b_n,\pi$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$.

Any hints? My attempt was to argue by contradiction, but I am not able to conclude.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking if $a_1+\frac1h b_1,\dots,a_n+\frac1h b_n,\pi$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, which is a small perturbation of a linearly independent set for large $h$. Since linear independence is an open condition (some determinants are non-zero) it will be linearly independent even without your restriction on $b_i$.

Comment: Linear independence over $\mathbb Q$ is not an open condition for $n$ real numbers: any real number can be approximated by rational numbers as much as is wanted. So the question seems not stupid to me.